# Apache CXF WSDL Resolution

Tags: java, wsdl, cxf

Using Apache CXF 2.7.7 if I publish a simple "HelloWorld" JAX-WS service and attempt to resolve the WSDL URL in a web browser using: "localhost:8080/service/HelloWorld?wsdl" the WSDL loads in the browser and everything looks great.

If I then add the below annotation which changes the SOAP Binding to 1.2 the WSDL resolution still works but the WSDL doesn't load in the browser, instead a download dialog is shown and the name of the WSDL is missing the file name extension in the download dialog (which is probably why it isn't loading in the browser).

```
javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPBinding.SOAP12HTTP_BINDING
```

The same behavior appears with the SOAP12HTTP_MTOM_BINDING

```
@javax.xml.ws.BindingType (value=javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPBinding.SOAP12HTTP_MTOM_BINDING)
```

Functionally everything works fine even with the BindingType annotation defined so this is just a minor annoyance but I'm wondering how I can get the correct WSDL resolution behavior when the default SOAP 1.1 binding is in use.

Comment: Created Apache JIRA issue to get this addressed by dev team.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CXF-5334

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I posted this issue on the Apache CXF JIRA and it was acknowledged as a defect. It has been fixed and will be included with the Apache CXF 2.7.8 release.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CXF-5334